# To copy values from a column range when condition met in excel

Tags: excel

Trying to solve myself, but totally stuck. I'm trying to copy values from column A when the value in the same row in column C is equal to value in same row column F. I need to move the formula down to include all values in column F.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

describe more I couldn't understand what you want to do.

```
Sub CopyRange()
dim i as long
for i=1 to Rows.count
   if cells(i,3)=Cells(i,6) then
       cells(i,1).copy
   end if
End Sub
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

With data in columns **A**, **C**, and **F** in rows *1* through *25*, enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/(C$1:C$25=F$1:F$25), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

in cell **G1** and copy downwards:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The only thing is that I need to copy the values of column LA in column LA1
 in the same row position that the S value, something like:   
  LA                LO           S          LA1              LA2       S
  43.42166667 -8.436666667 0002A   43.42166667 - 8.436666667 0002A
  
  Perhaps I can manage when your formula adapting it a bit. Thanks again.